# xdsoft_datetimepicker in modal window opens below viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

In the body there is one button, on click of which a modal window pops up. There are 2 xdsoft_datetimepickers in the modal-dialog. The last datetimepicker opens beyond the screen and the last few rows in the calendar are not visible.

The calendar opens up on click of the the input field to which it is associated in the modal-dialog.
On adding `overflow-y:auto` to `body.modal-open` we can scroll down to see the calendar.
The inbuilt property of the datepicker is it will appear below the input field if there is enough space otherwise above it.
But in my case it always appears below the input field thereby, hiding the last few rows.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged [twitter-bootstrap]…

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "pickerPosition" option value is 'top-right',code is

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    #this is other option
    ...
    pickerPosition: 'top-right',
});
```